# Alternative to array formula - Sort unique values

Tags: arrays, excel, uniqueidentifier

I have a worksheet (Old Report) on which I have the column "A". This contains a formula and that pulls numbers (eg: 21212, 122, 121212)

On a different sheet, I want the unique values formulated without spaces (vertically). I archieved this using this site:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&'Old Report'!$K$1&" "&'Old Report'!$L$1&"'!$A:$A"), MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("'"&'Old Report'!$K$1&" "&'Old Report'!$L$1&"'!$A:$A")),1,COUNTIF($L$1:L1, INDIRECT("'"&'Old Report'!$K$1&" "&'Old Report'!$L$1&"'!$A:$A"))), 0)
```

Problem is, this formula is lagging the worksheet.

Is there any other way to do this without arrays?

I do not mind using helper-columns.

Comment: Can you put an upper limit on the number of rows in 'Old Report'?

Comment: I can go with 2000 lines of formula. But not all 2000 would be populated. Only some would have numbers and some numbers would be repeated as I mentioned above.

Comment: Then it's worth first of all just replacing $A:$A with $A$1:$A$2000 and trying it because $A:$A implies 1,048,576 rows

Comment: Thanks Tom, that worked. How do I select your comment as answer?

Comment: I will put it as an answer -:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing $A:$A with $A$1:$A$2000 so the formula becomes

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&'Old Report'!$K$1&" "&'Old Report'!$L$1&"'!$A$1:$A$2000"), MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("'"&'Old Report'!$K$1&" "&'Old Report'!$L$1&"'!$A$1:$A$2000")),1,COUNTIF($L$1:L1, INDIRECT("'"&'Old Report'!$K$1&" "&'Old Report'!$L$1&"'!$A$1:$A$2000"))), 0)
```

this reduces the number of calculations from 1,048,576 to 2,000.

Of course it's still an array formula but array formulae are OK if you don't try to use them with too many rows.